# Forcing javac's -target version while building a Grails application

Tags: grails

There is a hello world Grails application. `grails war` produces .class files of version 1.5.

How to force Grails to produce 1.7 bytecode for an application?

Windows 7, Groovy 2.0.5, Grails 2.1.1, the only Java SDK is 1.7

Answer (score 3):

In `conf/BuildConfig.groovy` there's a property you can set:

```
grails.project.target.level = 1.7
```

Comment: Thank you. I just should note altering these options changes nothing for me - 1.5 class files are produced still - `minor version: 0,  major version: 49` (after a clean). Probably a bug...

Comment: Interesting. I just dug a little more and noticed that `grails.project.target.level` is present in the 2.0.0 docs, but not after. I wonder if they've removed it? I'll dig a bit more.

Comment: It does appear to still exist in the stock `BuildConfig.groovy` that comes with 2.2.0, however, so I assume it's still used. https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/0bcf9920a57faad2be950fc00ae31a13ca48650c/grails-resources/src/grails/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy

Answer (score 0):

groovyc 2.0.5 does not support compiling *.groovy file to class version 1.7 (seems only support 1.5-)