# Why does Groovy compiler apparently produce 1.5 version of Java?

Tags: java, groovy, version

After some problems with differences between JSE versions, I'm trying to log the Java compiler version used to compile (it's Groovy 2.1.9, Grails 2.3.8, Java 1.7.0_60 in fact).

After some rummaging around, I've constructed this piece of code to read the leading bytes of the class - see /http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout

(change the path to the class to match the package name):

```
class CompilerVersionSupport {

  public static String getVersion() {
    String classAsPath = 'com/my/organisation/CompilerVersionSupport.class';
    InputStream stream = (new CompilerVersionSupport()).getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(classAsPath);
    DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream (stream)

    assert( ins.readUnsignedShort() == 0xcafe )    
    assert( ins.readUnsignedShort() == 0xbabe )
    int minor = ins.readUnsignedShort();
    int major = ins.readUnsignedShort();
    ins.close();
    int javaVersion = major - 44 
    return "1.$javaVersion"
    }     
}
```

Trouble is, it returns 1.5.

What could be going on?

- Charles

Comment: How did you compile? Did you specify any target version?

Comment: In BuildConfig.groovy:   grails.project.target.level = 1.7

Comment: This question has come up before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176878/forcing-javacs-target-version-while-building-a-grails-application), but wasn't really answered.  Totally spit-balling here, but have you tried setting both *grails.project.source.level* and *grails.project.target.level* to 1.7?

Comment: Oh, and also are you using Grails directly?  Or are you integrating Grails with some other build tool (Gradle, Maven, etc)?  If so, you may need to set the desired bytecode in both your build tool and Grails itself.

Comment: @Keegan - thanks for the suggestions.  But yes, both items are set, and yes, running grails directly.

Answer (score 7):

The default Groovy behaviour is not to compile the code with the same bytecode version as the JDK being used. 1.5 is the default for compatibility reasons, IMHO. If you want the compiler to output newer bytecode you need to set that explicitly.

For example if you're using Maven to compile the code, you can use the [GMavenPlus](http://groovy.github.io/GMavenPlus/compile-mojo.html) plugin. See the description of the `targetBytecode` parameter.

If you're not using Maven you can use `-Dgroovy.target.bytecode=1.7` or research the possibilities for your particular build tool

Comment: "1.5 is the default for compatibility reasons" where did u get this information ?

Comment: Any suggestions how to do this with Grails?  I put _groovy.target.bytecode=1.7_ in BuildConfig.groovy, but I don't believe it looked at it, since it didn't object to a silly value either.

Comment: That's not exactly true, it depends on your environment.  1.5 is the default for GMavenPlus (following the pattern established by the Maven Compiler Plugin).  Gradle defaults to whatever JDK you use to compile.  Gant I assume would take the default that Groovyc sets (different, depending on Groovy version).  Grails seems to have its own defaults beside those of Gant.

Comment: @xwid I ended the sentence with "IMHO" :) So I'm not saying it's the absolute truth. But to me that is the most reasonable explanation - no to cut off people running older Java versions unless it's absolutely necessary. When they decide they can no longer live with what 1.5 bytecode offers they'll move higher up the ladder, I think.

Comment: To clarify things further: both the latest version of Groovy and 2.1.9 (which @CharlesW uses) take 1.5 as a default when there is no manual override. Check the Groovy [sources](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_2_1_9/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilerConfiguration.java).

Comment: @CharlesW How about simply trying to pass the configuration using the `-D` JVM notation? Have you tried that?

Comment: @daniel-kvasnicka is right, and Groovyc actually defaults to Groovy's default, so my statement on Groovyc's defaults was incorrect. I forgot about that.

Comment: @Daniel-Kvasnicka Well what do you know!   _grails -Dgroovy.target.bytecode=1.7 test-app CompilerVersionSpec_ did the job!   But I can't put that in every instance of running the unit tests.  How do I get that -D value into a grails configuration file?

Comment: @CharlesW I'm afraid I don't know the answer for Grails 2.1.x. With 2.3.x you could do that using [forked execution](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/commandLine.html#forkedMode) and pass the property in the config. If you can, upgrade. Grails 2.1 is hopelessly outdated and bug-ridden anyway (we took the plunge and it's worth it). Other than that you might try using e.g. Gradle for managing your Grails project - that might also open a few possibilities. But that's just guessing.

Comment: @Daniel-Kvasnicka Thanks - I am using Grails 2.3.8.  But forked execution is only about runtime, not about compile as far as I can see. :-(  Looks as though we've hit a bit of a brick wall...

Comment: @CharlesW Ooops, sorry, I've switched your Groovy and Grails versions :) However I believe you can have a `compile` key inside the `grails.project.fork` map and put your config there. Have you tried that? (I know the docs don't mention that but I believe it works)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Maven as the build tool, then chances are that it's using the `gmavenplus-plugin` to compile Groovy. To find out the target Java version of the bytecode generated I poked into the pom of the `gmavenplus-plugin` that my application uses: `~/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmavenplus/gmavenplus-plugin/1.5/gmavenplus-plugin-1.5.pom`.

Inside that file I saw this, notice `<javaVersion/>`,

```
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <mavenVersion>2.2.1</mavenVersion>
    <coberturaPluginVersion>2.7</coberturaPluginVersion>
    <javadocPluginVersion>2.10.1</javadocPluginVersion>
    <!-- these are properties so integration tests can use them -->
    <javaVersion>1.5</javaVersion>
    <dependencyPluginVersion>2.10</dependencyPluginVersion>
    <compilerPluginVersion>3.2</compilerPluginVersion>
    <junitVersion>4.12</junitVersion>
    <surefirePluginVersion>2.18.1</surefirePluginVersion>
    <pluginPluginVersion>3.4</pluginPluginVersion>
    <!-- this is a property so that site generation can use it -->
    <sourcePluginVersion>2.4</sourcePluginVersion>
    <!-- this is a property so that site generation and integration tests can use it -->
    <groovyVersion>2.4.1</groovyVersion>
  </properties>
...
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compilerPluginVersion}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${javaVersion}</source>
          <target>${javaVersion}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

I use IntelliJ for an IDE. IntelliJ is automatically setting the language level to Java 1.5. Even if I change it, when I re-import projects it resets back to Java 1.5 (I've fuzzed out sensitive information),

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is with the program you are using to find the class version. If the assertion is not enabled the stream doesnt read the first two unsigned shorts and hence the subsequent minor and major read statements results in 0Xcafe and 0xbabe respectively. Try enabling assertion or try using an if check.

```
public static String getVersion() throws Exception {
    String classAsPath = "com/my/organisation/CompilerVersionSupport.class";
    InputStream stream = (new CompilerVersionSupport()).getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(classAsPath);
    DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream(stream);

    if(ins.readUnsignedShort() != 0xcafe) throw new AssertionError("Invalid Class");
    if(ins.readUnsignedShort() != 0xbabe) throw new AssertionError("Invalid Class");
    int minor = ins.readUnsignedShort();
    int major = ins.readUnsignedShort();
    ins.close();
    int javaVersion = major - 44;
    return "1." + javaVersion;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but if that was true I think I'd get 0xbabe as the value, not 49.